# How to work with NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, xcode7

Please have a look at the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let url2 = NSURL (string: "http://leinelab.net/api/spaceapi.json")
  let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url2!);
  let response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?> = nil;
  let responseData = (try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(requestObj, returningResponse: response)) as NSData?

  let datastring = NSString(data: responseData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)  
  let datastring2 = String(datastring!)

  let text = ":true}"
  if datastring2.rangeOfString(text) != nil
  .
  .
  .
```

Somewhere here I have to work with NSURLConnection to access a website with self signed certificates but I don't know how. Code worked under Xcode 6, after upgrading to Xcode 7 it doesn't.

**Edit:**

This is the error message:

```
2016-01-22 22:45:56.678 LL-Test[3968:147205] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
```

Comment: Does the app crash or does it not compile? And do you get any error-message?

BTW: `NSURLConnection` is deprecated in iOS 9. You should use `NSURLSession`

Comment: Please can you edit your question so all your code is within a code block; it makes the question much easier to read. Also, add to the question some more detail about what does not work; is it a crash? is there an error message? does the code refuse to compile? Details please.

Comment: Build works, no crash. The app simply does not start. This is the error message: 2016-01-22 22:45:56.678 LL-Test[3968:147205] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Here is the complete code:

Comment: Sorry, complete code is too long.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use HTTPS since iOS 9. If you want to use HTTP, you have to configure exceptions in your `info.plist`.
Because of this behaviour, `datastring` and `datastring2` are `nil`, which causes the crash.

To configure the "App Transport Security"-exceptions, read this post in the Apple Developer Forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3544

Comment: HTTPS does not work, either. Reason seems to be the self signed certificate. But I think I found something in the forum post. Thank you very much!